# Netsuite Scheduled script can it be run every 3 minutes?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I see on the scheduled script deployment screen on Netsuite, the Repeat dropdown starts with a minimum of every 15 minutes. Can the interval be shortened somehow?

Answer (score 7):

The interval of scheduled scripts cannot be shortened to less than 15 minutes.

What you can do is set up a Suitelet that triggers the scheduled script to start. Once you get the External URL of the Suitelet you can plug it into an external cronjob service such as https://cron-job.org  and set it to run every 3 minutes.

Note that the scheduled script would be put on a queue either way so it may not start immediately after.

Answer (score 0):

The answer would be No. I think they are trying to prevent choking the queue so they only allow 15mins.